# Unimplemented Type 4 error when styling leaflet vector tiles

Tags: leaflet, gis, vector-tiles

I am trying to style the vector tiles on leaflet using vector grid plugin. The vector tiles are coming from my own server.

However when I try to specify the style using vector grid plugin, I get an error `unimplemented type 4`

How could I get rid of this error? Any plugin links or documentation will be really helpful!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60765560/postgresql-st-asmvt-to-vectortiles-to-leaflet-layer

Comment: @Ivan Sanchez. Both issues are somewhat not similar. When I tried to integrate the styling for vector tiles hosted on my server using vector grid plugin, I was using style.json in this format (https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/style). However I am using leaflet instead of mapbox.